# How to increase WebFlux WebClient's throughput?

Tags: spring-webflux

I would like to send some requests and receive responses with a high frequency.

My code as follows:

```
  Flux.fromIterable(params)
            .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(8))
            .subscribe(
              param -> {
                webClient
                    .get()
                    .uri(prefix.concat(Utils.urlEncoder(param)))
                    .header("K1", "V1"))
                    .exchange()
                    .subscribe(clientResponse -> {
                        log.info("");
                    });
            }
        );
```

The code runs well and the frequency is good.But when I try to change the `delayElements` method
's value(use **Duration.ofMillis(4)**),I found some exceptions.

```
    ERROR [reactor-http-nio-2] ContextHandler --- Error cannot be forwarded to user-facing Mono
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.io.IOException: Connection closed prematurely
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection closed prematurely
```

The code still can be running,but it generated some exceptions.

After that I decreased the value to **Duration.ofMillis(0)**.The code nearly can't be run.My console is full of exceptions.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files in system
```

Can I make the code's **throughput**
be better?

8 ms is good enough, but if I can increase the frequency, it's wonderful!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, several things might happen:

- if you're flooding a remote host, that host might think you're trying to do a DoS attack and will close incoming connections
- your local host might run out of file descriptors because you're creating too many connections

In general, you should use `limitRate` to limit the number of concurrent calls. `delayElements` is just introducing an artificial delay but does not take into account network latency or your server getting slow.

You could try instead:

```
Flux.fromIterable(params)
    .limitRate(25)
    .flatMap(param -> webClient
                         .get()
                         .uri(prefix.concat(Utils.urlEncoder(param)))
                         .header("K1", "V1"))
                         .exchange()
    )
    .subscribe(clientResponse -> { log.info(""); }, error -> { log.error(e); });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get `java.net.SocketException: Too many open files in system`
, it means you have reached limit on the number of file descriptors.

Try this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84227/limits-on-the-number-of-file-descriptors