# How do I queue work across multiple publishers in Reactor 3?

Tags: project-reactor

I'm creating a library for creating data processing workflows using Reactor 3. Each task will have an input flux and an output flux. The input flux is provided by the user. The output flux is created by the library. Tasks can be chained to form a DAG. Something like this: (It's in Kotlin)

```
val base64 = task<String, String>("base64") {
    input { Flux.just("a", "b", "c", "d", "e") }
    outputFn { ... get the output values ... }
    scriptFn { ... do some stuff ... }
}

val step2 = task<List<String>, String>("step2") {
    input { base64.output.buffer(3) }
    outputFn { ... }
    scriptFn { ... }
}
```

I have the requirement to limit concurrency for the whole workflow. Only a configured number of inputs can be processed at once. In the example above for a limit of 3 this would mean task base64 would run with inputs "a", "b", and "c" first, then wait for each to complete before processing "d", "e" and the "step2" tasks.

How can I apply such limitations when creating output fluxes from input fluxes? Could a TopicProcessor somehow be applied? Maybe some sort of custom scheduler or processor? How would back-pressure work? Do I need to worry about creating a buffer?

Comment: Have you looked at `limitRate` for Flux? There is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52703836/10264430

Comment: That would be perfect if I just needed to rate limit per flux, but I need to rate limit across multiple fluxes.

Comment: On second thought, it looks like this is just short for "flux.publishOn(Schedulers.immediate(), prefetchRate).subscribe()". Would this work if I ended up subscribingOn scheduler.elastic()?

Comment: am working on a library for DAG scheduling written using Kotlin coroutines . feel free to use or better still contribute  https://github.com/diarmuidkeane/dagupan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backpressure propagates from the final susbriber up, across the whole chain. But operators in the chain can ask for data in advance (prefetch) or even "rewrite" the request. For example, in the case of `buffer(3)` if that operator receives a `request(1)` it will perform a `request(3)` upstream ("1 buffer == max 3 elements so I can request my source enough to fill the 1 buffer I was requested").

If the input is always provided by the user, this will be hard to abstract away...

There is no easy way to rate limit sources across multiple pipelines or even multiple subscriptions to a given pipeline (a `Flux`).

Using a shared `Scheduler` in multiple `publishOn` will not work because `publishOn` selects a `Worker` thread and sticks to it.

However, if your question is more specifically about the `base64` task being limited, maybe the effect can be obtained from `flatMap`'s concurrency parameter?

```
input.flatMap(someString -> asyncProcess(someString), 3, 1);
```

This will let at most 3 occurrences of `asyncProcess` run, and each time one terminates it starts a new one from the next value from `input`.

Comment: Ah, ok it sounds like I'll have to work with just per-task concurrency. I'll give flatmap a try. Thank you!